# Size of an empty database too large

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Related to SQL Server 2016.

I have a database with five empty tables, let's say `db1`. I have another database with almost 100 tables and with a data in it, `db2`.

I observed that the size of `db1` data file is around `5gb`, while the size of `db2` data file is `3gb`.

Can anyone tell me why does the database with empty and lesser number of tables occupy more disk space than the one with more tables?

I checked for `nvarchar(max)` columns in `db1` and all the fields are typical `varchar` or `int`. I am aware of unused space however, I want to know what causes the size of `db1` to be more than `db2`.

Any reference material would be highly helpful too.

Thanks,
KV

Comment: .mdf or .ldf is full ?

Comment: The .mdf size of db1 is 5gb and for db2 it is 3gb.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely created the data file with minimum size of 5GB since you stated:

> I have a database with five empty tables, let's say db1. The .mdf size of db1 is 5gb

But you didn't say anything about INSERTS / DELETES.

Despite it being empty, the data file has reserved this space on disk. You can check / ensure it is empty via SSMS. [Pinal Dave Disk Usage Report](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/01/sql-server-ssms-disk-usage-report/) shows a way. You can also script this.

If this is the case, you can change the initial / minimum file size by Right Clicking on your Database > Properties > Files > changing the Inital Size (MB).

Then, you can shrink the file via [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Don't shrink the database, though.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/)

Comment: My bad, I believe you were right about reserved space. Thanks Simon.

Comment: You're welcome @SKV

Answer (score 0):

> I checked for `nvarchar(max)` columns in `db1` and all the fields are typical `varchar` or `int`. I am aware of unused space however, I want to know what causes the size of `db1` to be more than `db2`.

In this case, you should normally check what is database `recovery model`
(i.e. `select recovery_model_desc from sys.databases where database_id =  DB_ID()`) and database files (`.mdf and .ldf`) not the data type of the columns in tables.

- If the `.mdf` file consumed the size: Database might have created with `5GB`
- If the `.ldf` file consumed the size: Following might have happened:

  1. You created database `db1` with `recovery model` set to `full`
  2. Performed some DDL and DML activities in it
  3. Performed clean-up all the data
  4. Wondered, when looking at `db1` size, tables got no data but database size shows 5GB.

This causes due to `LOG` file, which maintains all the DDL/DML activities that been happened in the database, those activities not been truncated since the `LOG` backup NOT performed.

Here is some reference: [Understand recovery model](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5343/understanding-sql-server-recovery-models-and-transaction-log-use/)

---

Following queries might be helpful (in future events), to get insight of storage allocation within database using:

```
select  DB_NAME () AS DBName,
        SUM (CASE WHEN index_id = 0 -- HEAP (actual data)
                then (used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 end
            ) as HeapData_Mb
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN index_id = 1 -- Clustered Indexes (actual data)
                then (used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 end
            ) as Clustered_Index_Mb
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN index_id > 1 -- Clustered Indexes (actual data)
                then (used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 end
            ) as NonClusterd_Index_Mb
        ,max (row_count) as [RowCount]
        ,sum( (t.reserved_page_count * 8.00) / 1024) as Total_Reserved_Mb
        ,sum( ((reserved_page_count - used_page_count) * 8.00) /1024 ) as NonUsed_Mb
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats as T
go



select  OBJECT_NAME (object_id) as ObjectName,
        --Index_id, partition_number,
        SUM (CASE WHEN index_id = 0 -- HEAP (actual data)
                then (used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 end
            ) as RowData_Mb
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN index_id = 1 -- Clustered Indexes (actual data)
                then (used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 end
            ) as CluIndex_Mb
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN index_id > 1 -- Clustered Indexes (actual data)
                then (used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 end
            ) as NCluIndex_Mb
        ,max (row_count) as [RowCount]
        --,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY OBJECT_ID, PARTITION_NUMBER order by OBJECT_ID)
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
GROUP BY object_id
ORDER BY CluIndex_Mb desc, RowData_Mb desc, NCluIndex_Mb desc 
GO
```

**Edit: Additional note**

Once log file truncated, it releases used space, but won't reduce the actual file size by itself, you may want to shrink it manually via SSMS or following command.

*Note: in command `2` represents log file, `64` represents desired size. Ensure file id `select * from sys.sysfiles` before running `DBCC`*

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 64);
```

Comment: Thanks Shekar. You were right about what transactions might have happened on the database. However, I did take the log backup after those set of transactions. My log file is around 4mb, yet the data file is still at 5.2 Gb.

Comment: @SKV, well, that means, the 5gb might have set during database creation. However, pls have a look at my edit post. I believe, since log size already reduced there is no need of `SHRINKFILE`, you may leave `.mdf` file as is. Because, eventually the size increase, focus on **Auto Growth** configuration..